# LD error on existing file

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile, xlc

Good day everyone. The problem is this. I'm using a makefile to make an application. In it I have both LDFLAGS and LDLIBS (as well as others, but those 2 are relevant) specified and pointing to correct *.a files in existing folders. While trying to make an app I get the following error from LD:

> 0706-006 Cannot find or open library file: -l test001
>   ld:open(): No such file or directory

Those occur for every library in the project I try to link. The line in makefile where it occurs:

```
    appname: appname.o
    $(CC) -bnoquiet appname.o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

where

```
    LDFLAGS=-L$(LIBDIR)/
    LDLIBS=-ltest001 -ltest002 -ltest003 -ltest004
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `$(LIBDIR)` return the directory containing `test001.so`, `test003.so` and `test004.so`?

Comment: run `make VERBOSE=1` to see what is executed

Comment: Yes, it does. Running with VERBOSE doesn't say much, only that target is up to date.

Comment: Btw, these are not *.so files, but *.a files.

Comment: sorry, the lib file should have a name starting with `lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution I decided to pass those library files to linker as if they were object files. Like this:

```
    LIBS=$(LIBDIR)/test001.a $(LIBDIR)/test002.a $(LIBDIR)/test003.a $(LIBDIR)/test004.a
    ...
    $(CC) -bnoquiet appname.o -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

Not the greatest way of doing it I think. Although it seems in this case any solution would render the documented way (using -L and -l keys) useless. A shame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the library file names.

When you link with `-ltest001` the linker will look for files named `libtest001.so` (not `test001.so`).

**Edit** (to answer question 1 in the comments below):

Add a dependency to libtest001.so in your link step. 
Also add a rule to create libtest001.so.
It could look something like this:

```
# Change /a/b/ to a directory that is present in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
MY_LIBS="/a/b/libtest001.so"

mybinary: $(MY OBJS) $(MY_LIBS)
<tab> CC ...

/a/b/libtest001.so: test001.so
<tab> ln -s test001.so /a/b/libtest001.so
```

Comment: Is there a way to work around this without actually having to rename the files?

Comment: Create symbolic links. `ln -s test001.so libtest001.so`

Comment: 1) How will this look like in a makefile?
2) Is there really no other way to supply a full name of the library to make it visible?

Comment: 1) See edit in my answer. 2) That would depend on the linker. Check the documentation for options for your linker. I am not familiar with xlc.

Comment: So, just that I understand correctly: there is no common way to link a library that does not answer the naming convention, even though it has an appropriate format?

Comment: There is no standard, that I know of, that governs the linker options.